# How to modify classes for global use

Tags: python, class, global

my problem is a bit tricky to explain. Let me show you an example. I have the following class definitions:

```
class Person(object):     
    def __init__(self, name):         
        self.name = name  

    def say(self, stuff):         
        return self.name + ' says: ' + stuff     
    def __str__(self):         
        return self.name  

class Lecturer(Person):     
    def lecture(self, stuff):         
        return 'I believe that ' + Person.say(self, stuff)  

class Professor(Lecturer): 
    def say(self, stuff): 
        return self.name + ' says: ' + self.lecture(stuff)

class ArrogantProfessor(Professor): 
    def say(self, stuff): 
        return self.name + ' says: It is obvious that ' + Lecturer.lecture(self, stuff)

    def lecture(self, stuff):
        return 'It is obvious that ' + Lecturer.lecture(self, stuff)
```

Now I want to modify the any class but the `ArrogantProfessor` class so that I get the following:

```
>>> pe.say('the sky is blue')
Prof. eric says: I believe that eric says: the sky is blue 

>>> ae.say('the sky is blue')
Prof. eric says: It is obvious that I believe that eric says: the sky is blue
```

I should probably add, that `pe = Professor('eric')` and `ae = ArrogantProfessor('eric')`
The change is basically to add the `Prof.` title in the beginning so it is universal for all methods. Therefore I tried to add something like "title" to the `self.name` within the `__init__` method in the `Person(object)` class - but without success. Does anybody have a better idea Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're actually asking. The vast majority of your "question" here is just your homework assignment, not what you're having problems with. You haven't shown any of your own code, so we can't tell what's going wrong!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person(object):     
    def __init__(self, name):         
        self.name = 'Prof. ' + name
```

That answers your question as asked

Probably though you want something like:

```
class Professor(Person):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = 'Prof. ' + name
```

Then only `Professor` (and its sub-classes) will inherit the 'Prof.' title.

The key to this problem is overwriting `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

If you need the method `ArrogantProfessor.say()` to inherit from the method `Professor.say()`, while changing slightly its output, you will have to change the method `say()` in both classes.

In `Professor.say()`, you can add the title 'Prof' and in `ArrogantProfessor.say()`, you will have to call the parent method `say()` via `super()`.

```
class Professor(Lecturer):
    def say(self, stuff):
        return 'Prof. ' + self.name + ' says: ' + self.lecture(stuff)

class ArrogantProfessor(Professor):
    def say(self, stuff):
        return super(ArrogantProfessor, self).say(stuff)
    def lecture(self, stuff):
        return 'It is obvious that ' + Lecturer.lecture(self, stuff)
```

I recommend you to look at the documentation on inheritance and `super()`.

---

As [Ben Jarrett](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40352853/5825133) noted, you can also modify the `Professor.\__init__()` method instead of the above, but in that case, your output will become:

> ```
> Prof. eric says: I believe that Prof. eric says: the sky is blue
> Prof. eric says: It is obvious that I believe that Prof. eric says: the sky is blue
> ```